# I want to make a custom array in JS

Tags: javascript

recently I decided to make my own website and for make it, I have to build a specific array who takes objects groups.
Example :

```js
var my_array = [
  {y: '2015', a: 84},
  {y: '2016', a: 46},
  {y: '2017', a: 74},
  {y: '2018', a: 13},
  {y: '2019', a: 35},
  {y: '2020', a: 56}
]
```

And I have to build it inside a loop, my problem is when I modify y whith my_array.y = '2021',that modify all y elements, but I want modify just one element.

Comment: you cant use ```my_array.y = '2021'``` you have to also specify index of array ```my_array[0].y = '2021'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array full of objects. So you have to use the index of the array item you want to change or access.

For example the first item is:

```
my_array[0].y = '2021'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out for which element you want to change the y value. Like if you want to change the y value for the item where a = 13 then you can do the following,

```
const index = my_array.findIndex(item => item.a === 13);
if(index > -1) {
    my_array[index].y = yourYValue;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions, one of them is to find in your array the element you want to update

**Example:**

```
const index = my_array.findIndex( element => element.y == '2015' );
if(index > -1) {
   my_array[index].y = '2021';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over array items with forEach and do what needs to be done in the loop.

```
my_array.forEach((item) => {
   if (item.y == '2021') {
      // your code here
      }
);
```